# How to store data of a file using thrust::host_vector or device_vector?

Tags: cuda, thrust

The format of data is something like this:

```
TGCCACAGGTTCCACACAACGGGACTTGGTTGAAATATTGAGATCCTTGGGGGTCTGTTAATCGGAGACAGTATCTCAACCGCAATAAACCC
GTTCACGGGCCTCACGCAACGGGGCCTGGCCTAGATATTGAGGCACCCAACAGCTCTTGGCCTGAGAGTGTTGTCTCGATCACGACGCCAGT
TGCCACAGGTTCCACACAACGGGACTTGGTTGAAATATTGAGATCCTTGGGGGTCTGTTAATCGAAGACAGTATCTCAACCGCAATAAACCT
TGCCACAGGTTCCACACAACGGGACTTGGTTGAAATATTGAGATCCTTGGGGGTCTGTTAATCGAAGACAGTATCTCAACCGCAATAAACCT
```

Each line contains one sequence, I want to make a pair of (key ,value), key is one sequence and value is 1. Then use `reduce_by_key` to count the number of each sequence.

But I found that `thrust::host_vector` can only store one sequence, if I `push_back` the 2nd sequence the program crashed.
Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream input_subset("subset.txt");
    thrust::host_vector < string > h_output_subset;

    string s;
    while (getline(input_subset, s)) {
        h_output_subset.push_back(s);
    }
    cout << h_output_subset.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is that possible to store all of data in a `host_vector` or a `device_vector`? Or is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: The device vector version can't work because the GPU doesn't support `string`. However, the code you have posted *shoud* work, and does work with `std::vector`, which makes me think this is a bug in thrust

Comment: I can add that this does work up to thrust version 1.5, but thrust 1.7 and newer have problems.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Then is anything I can do to store the data and use thrust::reduce_by_key to do this work if I have to include thrust 1.8 lib?@talonmies

Comment: If you do actually want to do this on the device, use of `string` as a vector type will be a non-starter.  But if you come up with an alternate container/storage method (such as an array of char), it should be no problem to use thrust.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you for reply, it works! May I ask one more question:If I use reduce_by_key to deal with the data stored in host_vector, is this parallel?I mean I don't use kernel function or something  like that, can the program exploit the performance of CUDA/GPU?

Comment: In typical usage, operations done using host_vector  are not parallel and do not use the GPU..

Comment: @RobertCrovella You mean if I want to handle this in a parallel way implements some kernel function is nessesary?Then what are the advantages of thrust?

Comment: Perhaps you need to learn about thrust.  I can't teach you all of thrust in the space of a few comments.  Try reading the [thrust quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).  Thrust host_vector uses the host CPU, typically not parallel.  Thrust device_vector uses the GPU (or other parallel backend), and any operations (thrust algorithms) you do on a device vector will typically be done in parallel.  You don't have to implement any CUDA kernels of your own, in order to take advantage of parallel acceleration in thrust.

Comment: All right,thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The host_vector segfault was [confirmed](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/704) as a bug in `thrust::uninitialised_copy` and a patch has been applied to fix it.

The problem doing this with a `device_vector` is a genuine limitation of CUDA (no std::string support) and can't be avoided. An alternative would be to use a fixed length `char[]` array as a data member in a `device_vector`, or use a single large `device_vector` to hold all the string data, with a second `device_vector` holding the starting index of each sub-string within the character array.

Comment: Thank you for reply.I fixed the problem, but seems reduce_by_key cannot deal with key-value pair <string, int>.Is that possible to reduce by key where key is a string?